# How to create UITraitCollection with both size classes in code?

Tags: ios, swift, uitraitcollection

I have a simple extension for `UITraitCollection`:

```
extension UITraitCollection {

    var isIpad: Bool {
        return horizontalSizeClass == .Regular && verticalSizeClass == .Regular
    }
}
```

Before, I have needed to write tests for this (using TDD):

```
let traitCollection = UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: .Regular) //the init is either for vertical or horizontal at time
traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass = .Regular //error

XCTAssertTrue(traitCollection.isIpad)
```

But the error is:

> Cannot assign to property: `horizontalSizeClass` is a get only property.

What should I do then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have found solution:

```
let compactTraitCollection = UITraitCollection(traitsFromCollections: [UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: .Compact), UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .Compact)])
XCTAssertFalse(compactTraitCollection.isIpad)

let regularTraitCollection = UITraitCollection(traitsFromCollections: [UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: .Regular), UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .Regular)])
XCTAssertTrue(regularTraitCollection.isIpad)
```